# python variable scope with only function

Tags: python

I don't understand why this code prints `None` in `b()`:

```
# coding: utf-8                                                                               


saber = None
rider = dict()


def a():
    saber = 'ex'
    rider['a'] = 'b' 
    print saber
    print rider


def b():
    print saber
    print rider


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a() 
    b()
```

When `b()` is called, printing `saber` results in `None` being printed. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`saber` is `None` in `b()` because you have defined it as a global variable with a value of `None` and have not defined a local variable of the same name in that function. In `a()` you defined `saber` with a value of `"ex"` and when you printed that variable, that's what you got. But that value of `saber` went away when the function finished, because it is local to the function, and that's what local variables do.

Now you might ask why `rider` was changed in `a()` when `saber` was not. But in fact, `rider` was not changed. You did not assign to the name `rider` in `a()`, so the global variable `rider` was used. The *contents* of `rider` were changed (you added a new key/value pair) but `rider` itself *is still the same dictionary object it was when you first defined it.* And that's why when you print it in `b()` you get the changed dictionary. Both functions are using the global variable `rider` because there is no local variable of the same name "hiding" it.

Answer (score 6):

In `a()`, you are re-declaring `saber` locally, and so it references a local variable and not the global that you declared in the beginning of your code. See [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) for more information. The solution is to declare `saber` global at the beginning of `a()`:

```
def a():
    global saber
    saber = 'ex'
    rider['a'] = 'b' 
    print saber
    print rider
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this in `a()`:

```
global saber
saber = 'ex'
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/423379/201359) for a similar question. Basically, if you don't specify that `saber` is global, it'll be interpreted as local to the function. We don't have to do the same for `rider` because we're not actually reassigning it, only modifying its contents.

Answer (score 3):

Check my comments in the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

saber = None
rider = dict()
# use id() to get memory address of this object
print id(saber)
print id(rider)



def a():
    saber = 'ex'
    rider['a'] = 'b'
    print id(saber)
    # as you can see here, you have created a new object inside function a which replace the global variable
    print saber
    print id(rider)
    # you are using the same object from global 
    print rider


def b():
    print id(saber)
    # you are using the global variable here
    print saber
    print id(rider)
    # you are using the global variable here
    print rider


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a()
    b()
```

OUTPUT:

```
35731224
506032968
35662984
ex
35731224
{'a': 'b'}
506032968
None
35731224
{'a': 'b'}
```

Answer (score 1):

saber and rider are global, but in a() you have:

```
def a():
    saber = 'ex'     # local variable saber, rather than the global one
    rider['a'] = 'b' # global variable rider
    print saber
    print rider
```